# Eclipse IDE is installed but won't open

Tags: eclipse

I have installed gcc/g++, JDK/JRE, and Python before installing Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers. After the installation was complete it showed me a launch now option in the Eclipse installation program like this.

[image]

However I can't open it again in the root folder if I close Eclipse.

[image]

Also please tell me how to add Eclipse to the applications menu.

Comment: Why is it installed in the root users home folder? You should install it somewhere you have read access as a normal user.

Comment: idk it was the default directory in the installation. Ill change it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create `Eclipse.desktop` file in `.local/share/applications`, then run `sudo chmod a+x Eclipse.desktop` and you will be able to add Eclipse to Favourites and also It's going to be visible in Applications.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Eclipse
Terminal=false
Name=Eclipse
Exec=/home/user/eclipse/java-2020-03/eclipse/eclipse
Type=Application
Icon=/home/user/eclipse/java-2020-03/eclipse/icon.xpm
StartupWMClass=Eclipse
```